# Is there a word that means "being of X trait"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb that means "being of X trait"? When you give the definition of a certain adjective, you use the verb "is", but this leads to an imprecision in speech that sounds awkward, so is there a better way to express the idea?

Here's an example:

> The definition of the word "whitish" is any color **between white and
>   gray.**

But using is in the above example sounds incorrect and imprecise, is there a better way to word this?

Comment: The only thing that looks unusual to me about that sentence is the styling used. I would say *The definition of the word "whitish" is:* ***Any colour between white and grey.*** Although the exact styling can vary, the definitional text (along the lines of what you'd find in a dictionary) would normally be a complete sentence—as opposed to just the phrase that you've put in bold. But there's nothing unusual about the use of *is* itself.

Comment: Not sure why you think that the use of "is" leads to imprecision. If you are concerned about possible ambiguity, maybe "*The word 'whitish' is defined as any colour between white and grey*" would be more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of [State of Being](https://www.thoughtco.com/verb-of-being-1692485) verbs (is/are/am/were/etc.) are used in this situation.

This does include the verb *is*, which is used correctly in the sample sentence you provide. It may sound incorrect and imprecise to you, but it is normal and well-understood by a native speaker.

> The road *is* bumpy.
>
> The pie *will be* delicious when it is done.
>
> I *am* happy.
>
> Her shirt *was* purple.

More precise verbs can be used, but these are specific to the trait or quality in question.

> The road *looks*/*feels* bumpy.
>
> The pie *will taste* delicious when it is done.
>
> I *feel* happy.
>
> Her shirt *looked* purple.